# Bootstrap: limit text to a portion of list group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a list-group, where there is some text as a usual list, but on the right side, there is an up and down button. I have used bootstrap's default list group, and put some buttons inside it with the class pull-right. The problem is, if the text is too long, the buttons placement gets bad.

This can be seen in this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qd0z7Ljc/

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2> Front </h2>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">

  Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Up</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right">Do</button>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Up</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right">Do</button>
    </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Up</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right">Do</button>
    </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Up</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right">Do</button>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

I want an effect where the text occupies say, 80% of the space, while the remaining 20% is always the up/down buttons to give a uniform visual effect.

Comment: A `button` inside an anchor `a` is not valid HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround both `btn` elements with a `<div class="pull-right">` and remove the `pull-right`. This makes the two button elements stick together. As the `pull-right` class takes the buttons outside of the document flow they don't influence the height of the `list-group-item`. Fix this by adding a `clearfix` class to the `<a class="list-group-item">`

Now you have two different options

1. Place the text in the `a` tag after the new `<div>`. This makes the browser place the text after placing the buttons, making the buttons always appear on the top right of the item. If the text is really long however it might wrap around the buttons. If you don't want that
2. Bootstrap allows the grid to be nested. This means you can add another `.row` and several `col-xs-*` columns inside the `a` tag allowing you to put the text in the left and the buttons in the right column.

See http://jsfiddle.net/qd0z7Ljc/ for both options